# Testing the creation of objects in a factory method

Tags: c++, unit-testing, design-patterns, tdd, design-principles

At the moment I'm writing a test-driven project, and I stuck in testing the following behaviour.

I got an interface called `Menu` to which one can add dynamically entries through an `addEntry`-Method. There is another class which contains the `Menu` object. Let's call it `MenuPresenter`. When a specific method (e.g. `someAction(string title)`) is called the `MenuPresenter` should instantiate an `Entry` object with the received title and add it to the `Menu` object. The instantiation of the `Entry` object happens in a factory method inside the `MenuPresenter`.

[image]

The tested behaviour should be `WhenSomeActionIsCalledShouldAddAnEntryContainingTitleToMenu`

But I don't find the right way to write the test. I figured out two main possibilities to test it, but I actually don't like both of them because of the (later) mentioned disadvantages.

1. Implement a `MenuSpy` inheriting from `Menu`, which has a `getAddedEntry`-Method. Like this you can extract the added `Entry` and check the state of the object
   `EXPECT_TRUE(entry->getTitle() == title);`

**Disadvantages:** To check the state of the `Entry` object I have either to extend the API of the Interface with getter-Methods which are only used for testing reasons or to use public member variables. This allow every client get access to the internal structure of each Implementation of `Entry`. Thus the clients are coupled to internal structure.

2. Extend the system through an `EntryFactory` interface which has a
   `makeEntry(std::string title)`-method. Like this one can implement an `EntryFactorySpy` and can check if the `makeEntry`-method is called with the correct parameters (title). In another Test we can implement an `EntryFactoryStub` which returns a specific `Entry` object. Then we can check (via a `MenuSpy`) if the `MenuPresenter` has added the received entry from the factory to the menu. The instantiation of the `Entry` object is then tested in a unit test for a the factory.

**Disadvantages:** Because I test the call of the factory's `makeEntry`-method the algorithm of using a factory to create entries is fix. The test is tightly coupled to the internal structure of the `MenuPresenter`. Changing the algorithm (e.g. using now the factory method would break the test, without that the expected behaviour of the application breaks.

For application's behaviour it should be unimportant if the `MenuPresenter` creates the `Entry` itself of if it uses a `EntryFactory`. This is why I'd prefer the first way. But I don't want the client's of `Entry` to be coupled to the internal structure of `Entry` only because of testing reasons.

This is only an example of my problem. In reality the entry not only created with a string. It gets other complex objects as shared_ptr. This is another reason, why I dont want to use public getter-methods. Like this one could extract the complex object from the `Entry` and change it (Yes, I could give out a const shared_ptr, but this seems to be not a good practice to me.)

The Question is, does anyone know a testing pattern or a solution that adresses my problem? Meaning testing if a correct `Entry` object is added to the `Menu`object without being coupled to tight to the algorithm or the internal structure of `Entry`?

Comment: maybe duplicate [Unit testing of private methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3676664/5980430)

Comment: Wondering what Menu does with an Entry if it can't see the title?  Seems like the test that the correct Entry was added should be based on some observable behavior of the Entry?

Comment: Do the +/- notations indicate class methods vs. instance methods?

Comment: No this is for the visibilities

Comment: @JonReid "Do the +/- notations indicate class methods vs. instance methods? " - I think `+` is `public` method, `-` is `private` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a java developer, I never exercise TDD in c++, but I maybe can describe what you want to test as you mentioned above.

In Classic TDD, the `MenuPresenter` should be more like a mini-integration test as Martin Fowler has said in [Test Isolation](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TestIsolation).

> In essence classic xunit tests are not just unit tests, but also mini-integration tests. As a result many people like the fact that client tests may catch errors that the main tests for an object may have missed, particularly probing areas where classes interact.

In Classic TDD Use real objects if possible and a [Test Double](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) if it's awkward to use the real thing when testing `MenuPresenter`. So ask yourself what expected effect happens when an `Entry` added in a `Menu`. testing `Menu` will be adding an titled `Entry`only is meaningless, you should test what is behavior effected after an `Entry` added.let's say an `Entry` added will display as a titled `MenuItem`, so you just assert real `Menu` object that whether displayed a `MenuItem` with expected title.

Indeed, `WhenSomeActionIsCalledShouldAddAnEntryContainingTitleToMenu` test is already exposing `someAction` implementation details by its name, and coupling the test to the implementation `someAction`, one the other hand, when you change the algorithm of `someAction` the test will be failed.  you maybe add a test as `displaysAnTitltedMenuItemInMenuWhenSomeActionIsCalledWithinATitle`.

As you can see the test will be coupling to the implementation in anyway. we only can do is make the test coupling to the implementation as **lower** as possible, so that, we just change a little tests when the implementation changed.

if you found the `Menu` is an awkward one, you can use a `MenuSpy` instead, and then write some [IntegrationContractTest](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/IntegrationContractTest.html) within `MenuSpy` & `MenuImpl`. as you can see that the Test using `MenuSpy` is a little higher coupling to the implementation than a real `Menu`, because we expects a titled `Entry` was added in `MenuSpy` not the effects of `Menu` after a titled `Entry` added.

let the `MenuSpy` to checking whether a titled `Entry` was added, for example:

```
someAction(title);

menuSpy->hasReceivedATitledEntry(title);
```

**OR**: you maybe checking a added `Entry` whether is a `CheckableEntry` in `getAddedEntryTitle` method before title returned.

```
someAction(title);

EXPECT_TRUE(menuSpy->getAddedEntryTitle() == title);
```